# Generating individual HTML email signatures via Dreamweaver or?

Tags: automation, dreamweaver, email-signature

I am a marketer/graphic designer with very minimal knowledge of coding. My company is currently in process of updating our website, and we paid the web designer to create an HTML email signature for us.  I am now tasked with creating signatures for ~100 employees and training them to install the signature.

I have a subscription to Adobe Creative Suite, and am very familiar with InDesign, Photoshop and Illustrator, so my first thought was to try using Dreamweaver to make the edits. Using that program, I can open the html file and manually make the edits to create an personalized email for a specific user, but I don't want to have to go through the entire process manually for each of our employees.

I was wondering if there was some way to implement a data merge process with Dreamweaver, where I could use a csv file (for example) and have it populate the applicable fields into an email signature template automatically.

I did some on-line digging which pointed me towards creating a template in Dreamweaver. I have been able to do that (although I still can't figure out how to make the mailto link an editable region), but now I can't find any information about how to link the template with the data source and create the individual email signatures.

Can anyone point me to where I can find step by step instructions for setting up this type of process?  I am willing to use a different app if there is something better/easier, but I can't afford to buy anything new.  Also, as I said at the very beginning, I only have very minimal coding knowledge, so if scripting is my best option, please point me at a pre-existing script that I can re-use with only very minimal edits.

BTW--I am using Windows 10 and Dreamweaver CC 2017

Comment: I would think the individuals would need to update their own signatures in their email program. If using Microsoft products, open the signature in Word, which understands html, ctrl-A to select all, ctrl-C to copy, open Outlook, go to settings or preferences, find the Signature, and ctrl-V to paste.

Comment: I am specifically avoiding using Word so that I don't get all of the extra garbage that it adds when it creates HTML. And we will be installing by saving the signature into the user's signature folder, so that Outlook doesn't make any "helpful" changes that we don't want. That is exactly the reason why I need to create the signatures for each person--so that I control the way they look, not some Microsoft programmer from afar.